# Move an existing Clustered columnstore index into a different file group

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016, clustered-index

I am trying to move an existing Clustered Columnstore Index from one file group to another file group but couldn't find any command to do that.

Code what I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE CCSI ON [dbo].[t179_s1_LOSS_ByEvent_ORIGINAL_440F6776-6185-4416-89D8-B69334457B25] 
WITH ( MOVE TO FG_1 );
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 281
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 281
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like a clustered index, recreate it on the target filegroup with DROP_EXISTING.  eg

```
create table foo(id int, a int)
create clustered columnstore index cci_foo on foo

go

create clustered columnstore index cci_foo 
on foo
with (drop_existing=on)
on fg2
```